# Restore Mongo DB backup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

I have mongodb backup files as in.wt and.bson and some wieldtrigger files. I have installed mongodb on a new server and copied backed up files to /var/lib/mongo folder and restarted the mongodb service. It is not showing any DB's in MongoDB Compass. When I copied, the original files were overwritten. I also tried with the below command but no luck.

mongorestore -d dbname--c collection /var/lib/mongo/storage.bson""

Please help with how to restore the DB's and collections on a new server.

When I change /etc/mongod.conf bind ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and save. After starting the service, it fails to start and the error is "child processes exited 100."

Comment: Did you backup **all** files from `dbPath` folder?

Comment: Yes, I have backed up.

Comment: Then simply copy all files into `dbPath` and restart the MongoDB

Comment: Yes i tried, but its overwriting already existed files of mongo db. I have path /varl/lib/mongo and no folder like dbPath.

Comment: `dbPath` is the parameter in the configuration file where data is stored (most likely `/var/lib/mongo` in your case) How do you start the service? Did you empty the existing folder before you copy the files from backup? Did you stop the mongod before?

Comment: Yes, i stopped the service and copied all files to /var/lib/mongo and i emptied the existing folder. Once i copied i started the service.

Comment: It should work like that. Are you really sure you set `/var/lib/mongo` as `storage.dbPath`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb/67043090#67043090

Comment: -- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
Jun 07 07:44:07 ip-172-31-33-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal mongod[1226]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Jun 07 07:44:07 ip-172-31-33-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal mongod[1226]: forked process: 1229

Comment: Jun 07 07:44:07 ip-172-31-33-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal mongod[1226]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
Jun 07 07:44:07 ip-172-31-33-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal mongod[1226]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Jun 07 07:44:07 ip-172-31-33-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=100
Jun 07 07:44:07 ip-172-31-33-216.ap-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed

Comment: After copying files and starting the service, the service gets failed.

Comment: Please edit your question for such additional information, instead of putting them into a comment. Did you try to start manually like `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` as adviced in the error message? Did you check the mongod log file? (typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`)